# How to run this lisp functional programming code?

Tags: functional-programming, lisp, common-lisp

I am trying to run this code that supposedly removes duplicates from a sorted list of numbers.

```
    (defun unique (x)
(cond( (null x) x )
( (null (cdr x)) x )( (equal (car x) (cdr x)) (unique (cdr x)) )( t (cons (car x) (unique (cdr x))) )))
```

I am trying to call this function by typing:

```
(print (unique '(2 2 3 4 4 5)))
```

My output is currently shown as follows:

(2 2 3 4 4 5)

Clearly, this doesn't seem to be removing the duplicates, if anything at all.

Answer (score 4):

There is an error in the form: `(equal (car x) (cdr x))`. `car` returns the first element of a list, while `cdr` returns the rest of the list, so the comparison is not between the first and the second element of the list, but between the first element and the list without the first element (and this comparison will always produces false for regular lists).

To correct the error, the function should use `cadr` instead of `cdr`: `(equal (car x) (cadr x))`: the function `cadr` (or its synonym `second`) is equivalent to `car (cdr` and returns the second element of a list. So this is the correct version:

```
CL-USER> (defun unique (x)
           (cond ( (null x) x )
                 ( (null (cdr x)) x ) 
                 ( (equal (car x) (cadr x)) (unique (cdr x)) )
                 ( t (cons (car x) (unique (cdr x))) )))
UNIQUE
CL-USER> (unique '(1 1 2 2 3))
(1 2 3)
```

Comment: "this comparison will always produce false" this calls for a counter-example :-) Consider `(let* ((tail (list 0 1 2)) (list (cons tail tail))) (assert (equal (car list) (cdr list))))`

Comment: Yes, and another counter-example is `(1 . 1)` :). I omitted “for regular lists”. Corrected, thanks @coredump.

Comment: It looks like this doesn't work for test case (print (unique '(2)))
(print (unique '(2 2 3 4 4 5))), since it doesnt remove the extra 4

Comment: @Greg, it works for me: `(unique '(2 2 3 4 4 5))` produces `(2 3 4 5)`. On which system did you test it?